# Splitting XML into multiple XML files using paging

Tags: c#, xml, paging

I have a dictionary of jobs which need writing to XML for site map usage.

I cannot have the files going over 50,000 records and so need a way of paging this information or something along these lines.

This method decides if the total number of jobs is greater than 30,000.

How could I change my else to include paging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `Skip` before `Take` in your (inner) for loop.

```
int newJobCount = JobCount / 4;

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
          Test(item.Value.BrandName, item.Value.CountryCode, item.Value.Jobs.Values.Skip(newJobCount * i).Take(newJobCount).ToList());
}
```

See http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2012/03/29/c.net-little-wonders-skip-and-take.aspx.

**Side note regarding newJobCount**

If you want to limit number of jobs per page to 3000, then following will be better:

```
int pageCount = JobCount/3000 + (JobCount % 3000 == 0 ? 0 : 1);

for (int i = 0; i < pageCount; i++)
{
    Test(item.Value.BrandName, item.Value.CountryCode, item.Value.Jobs.Values.Skip(3000 * i).Take(3000).ToList());
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! Works perfectly! Could you explain the pageCount Line to me as I am struggling to understand what == 0 ? 0: 1 does?

Comment: Say JobCount is 4500. Then JobCount/3000 will return 1 for pageCount. So only 3000 jobs would be processed. The '== 0 ? 0: 1' part ensures that if there is any remainder (in this case 1500) then we add another page to cover it.